# How to get URI data from onActivityResult method to send to another activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, onactivityresult

The Uri which I got in the onActivityResult method,I tried to make global Uri variable to get that Uri to send it using Intent putExtra method to another activity.. but it's showing cannot resolve symbol.

The **selectedImage** variable in onActivityResult method,I want the value of that Uri variable outside the method so that I can send that Uri to another activity using Intent.

How to get the value of it as the return type of onActivityResult is void?

Help me or is there any other way?

public void onClickPickImage(View view){

```
    Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
   startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);//zero can be replaced with any action code

    Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(pickPhoto , 1);//one can be replaced with any action code
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
    switch(requestCode) {
        case 0:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();

            }

            break;
        case 1:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();

            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot help without code

Comment: Can you post code?

Comment: see `Intent#getData` / `Intent#setData`

Comment: yes, use `getData` / `setData`, what kind of problems do you face with it?

Comment: I want to send that Uri to another activity..ok let me check using setData.

Answer (score -1):

Just declare the below code above Oncreate

```
private Uri fileUri;
```